# >> and << and data types in C++

Tags: c++, types, bit-shift

I have looked over the guide given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141525/absolute-beginners-guide-to-bit-shifting), but I still don't understand bit-shifting. In particular I am confused about the data types come into play.

The following:

```
unsigned int a = pow(2,31);
cout << (a << 1);
```

indeed produces 0 as I expect because the `int` is 32 bits, so moving the `1` to the left, pushes it into nothing.

But the following

```
unsigned int a = 1;
unsigned char b = (unsigned char)a;
cout << (unsigned int)(b<<8);
```

produces 256. Why is that? My guess would have been that a `char` is 8 bit and so moving 1 left 8 places should give zero.

Is there a function/shift that does this? (i.e. evaluates `1<<8` to 0).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Narrow integral values are promoted to `int` or `unsigned int` before being used. It's called *integral promotion*.

Comment: Is there a way to have the << work on 8 bits as I had assumed?

Comment: @Thomas: I believe `(unsigned int)(unsigned char)(b<<8)` would do